# How to create more than once Notification in android class?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

How do you go about making a new notification with one application inside of one class?
I am trying to launch more than one notification from one class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [notification example in the guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateANotification), when you call [NotificationManager.notify](http://NotificationManager) you can pass a different `id` value to create a new status bar notification.